# Azure Restore takes ages to restore a Server

Tags: windows, azure

I'm currently writing my Disater Recovery Plan, and tried to restore a whole server from Azure Backup (Approx 500Gb of data).

I just leaved after two days as the restore was only 20Gb out of 500...

Today i needed to restore a simple Excel Spreadsheet (90Kb), it takes 10 mintues to recover.

We have a Fiber Connection here, with 200 Mbps Down / 100Mbps Up so that's not a bandwidth issue.

Is that the same for everyone or just us ?

Thanks :)

Comment: So this is a restore from Azure to an on-site system? You say that bandwidth isn't an issue but have you looked at the utilization of your internet connection before and during the restore? What about latency?

Comment: Yes this is a restore from an On Premises Server, to another On Prem Server to test the restore time. 

I started the restore when users weren't at work.

I checked my bandwidth at this time, which were good.

I didn't checked the latency however, we never had latency issues so i don't htink this is due to latency.

I checked the Throttling settings on Azure Backup Agent, which is not configured so it should use the full bandwidth available.

Comment: OK. Until you check the bandwidth utilization and latency during a restore you can'y confidently and unequivocally rule them out. That would be my first step.

Comment: I will give it another try so and take some captures of my network utilisation.

Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. I'll await your test results.

Comment: I just launched the file Restore Process. Currently on Estimating Size of Backup Items. Network 100kbits/sec usage, 1ms latency to Gatway, 3ms to 8.8.8.8 DNS. Server Disk Usage near 0, RAM Usage 40%, CPU 30 to 60%.

I know that's not the part when network can cause throttle, just writing here to save it here for the next part.